# call enter in .bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I call .bat file from remote machine. In this .bat file I call .exe file, which want user to press Enter, after this .exe worked.
So, my question: is there any option to pass Enter in .bat file? Thanks for any help.
code of my .bat file

```
pushd \\server_name\\myfolder\\Reports\\
reportsupload.exe -e "http://mysite/ReportServer"
popd
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a solution that does not rely on third-party programs, that will depend on how the program `reportsupload.exe` handles the request for pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. If it reads the standard input stream, you *might* be able to manage it by changing the line to `echo. | reportsupload.exe -e "http://mysite/ReportServer"`; if it's handled by scanning the keyboard for the keypress,  this will not work.

There may be third-party programs that can be configured to detect when the computer or a program is in a given state and trigger an action based on that state, but I'm not aware of any that don't require user intervention (e.g., pressing a key to execute a macro).

Comment: I'd use `echo/| ...` as `echo.` might fail under rare circumstances and the _space_ before `|` was output too...

Comment: @aschipfl - The sixty-four dollar question, though, is whether the request to press enter is handled as stdin or keyboard strobe.

Comment: ...and querent may not know the answer to that; he may not have written the program in question.

Comment: Actually I meant through accepting your answer or commenting... ;-)