# Use batch file to input letter to perform action in cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, automation, command-prompt

I have an .exe that runs in command prompt, it then asks me to press a letter to perform a task. I want a batch file that runs the .exe file and presses y to perform the action. This is what I have so far:

```
start cmd.exe /k ""C:\Users\mayes\Documents\Utilities\Macros\Second Keyboard Macros\Intercept\intercept\intercept.exe""
```

All what it does is open the .exe file. I need it to press y also.

Demonstration of what I want the batch file to do:

https://media.giphy.com/media/Ujsia9OeUqJuo/giphy.gif

Comment: start cmd.exe /k ""C:\Users\mayes\Documents\Utilities\Macros\Second Keyboard Macros\Intercept\intercept\intercept.exe"" /Q

Comment: /Q means quiet mode.

Comment: This depends on whether or not intercept.exe has any command-line options. You _might_ be able to say `echo y|"C:\Users\mayes\Documents\Utilities\Macros\Second Keyboard Macros\Intercept\intercept\intercept.exe"` but I'm not confident enough to post that as an answer.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44758419/call-enter-in-bat-file/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is another much easier way, the program has built in arguments,

```
C:\Stack\intercept>intercept.exe /help

*** Keyboard Remapper v. 1
*** Based on Oblitum Interception http://oblita.com/Interception.html

Use /help for help on command-line options

Command line parameters:
        /ini path       oile.ini specify alternate config file (optional)
        /apply                non-interactive, apply filters on startup (optional)

C:\Stack\intercept>
```

if you type `/help` so just make a shortcut with a `/apply` and you're **GOLDEN!** it's a useful tip to check console applications for built in arguments and options by typing `/help`.

Answer (score 0):

you can send keys with vb script witch can be run from batch.
Try this:

```
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.run"C:\Users\mayes\Documents\Utilities\Macros\Second Keyboard Macros\Intercept\intercept\intercept.exe"
WScript.Sleep 1500
shell.SendKeys"{Y}"
shell.SendKeys"{ENTER}"
```

save it as `.vbs`, and it you want to run it from batch you can use:

`cscipt "nameoffile".vbs`

hope it works for you!

Comment: When I run the .vbs file it asks me which program to run it with.
[link](https://i.imgur.com/vGbUe0L.jpg)

Comment: odd, is the icon, and file type of of the script file changed to "vb script"? Try running the script from cmd with `cscript "filename".vbs`